# Is there an SO icon or badge or graphic to use in one's credentials list outside of SO?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, icons

I recently encountered a neat idea but it did not register on me until it was too late (i.e. the URL was long gone from my mind and browser). What I want to do is add a series of badges on my own web page with my "credentials", which would include Stack Overflow, LinkedIn, Friend of Red Gate, CodePlex developer, SourceForge developer, and perhaps a couple others. Is there any repository of such logos/graphics/badges? Assuming not, are there any standards for sizes or shapes? Or how about anyone else's examples? And, while I am wishing, what would be especially nice is a Stack Overflow logo that included one's *current* rep count (i.e. it would update itself as rep changes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> And, while I am wishing, what would be
>   especially nice is a Stack Overflow
>   logo that included one's current rep
>   count (i.e. it would update itself as
>   rep changes).

Yes, there is one, it's in your profile under the flair tab:

[image: screenshot of tab]

Comment: It's in the profile tab.. Wait where did it go? It was there last week!

Comment: yep it's gone.. can't find it either, can't keep up!- I think I feel a delete coming on before the downvotes.. oops

Comment: have a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/vF70t.png

Comment: @Popular Demand.. thank you that did said it better, and should I also say +1 for the hand drawn circle ;)

Comment: since you seemed to like it, I added it to your answer.